# How to get coordinates at specific distance in a path

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]I am using google map ios sdk, My problem is i have to get coordinates for every 1000 meter on a poly line in map. now i am able to get number of location in given path and able to accesses them using the following code snip.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getCoordinates {

    pathCoordinatesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  GMSMutablePath *path = [VTDirectionManager getPath];
    NSLog(@"count %d",path.count);

    for (int i=0 ; i<path.count; i++) {

        if (i+1 > path.count) {
            return pathCoordinatesArray;
        }
        for (int j = i+1; j<path.count; j++) {

            CLLocationCoordinate2D sourceCoordinate = [path coordinateAtIndex:i];
            CLLocation *sourceLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:sourceCoordinate.latitude longitude:sourceCoordinate.longitude];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationCoordinate = [path coordinateAtIndex:j];
                        CLLocation *destinationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:destinationCoordinate.latitude longitude:destinationCoordinate.longitude];

            BOOL check ;

          check = [self checkDistanceForSource:sourceLocation andDestination:destinationLocation];

            //jump to next 1000 distance position

            if (check) {
                i = j;
            }
        }




    }


    return pathCoordinatesArray;



}

-(BOOL)checkDistanceForSource:(CLLocation*)source andDestination:(CLLocation*)destination {

    CLLocationDistance distance = [source distanceFromLocation:destination];

    if (distance > 1000) {

        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:destination.coordinate.latitude longitude:destination.coordinate.longitude];

        [pathCoordinatesArray addObject:location];
        return YES;
    }
    return  NO;

}
```

Suppose if i have 5000 meter distance path , then i have to get 5 coordinates ,each at 1000 meters position sequentially.

i think  it is wrong code . Suggest me with optimized code

see the image each points are 1000 metered distance .

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: @jogendra : bentween point A and point B i need to get coordinates on each 1000 meters

Comment: @jogendra: i updated my question with some code  please check it . i think  it is wrong code . Suggest me with optimized code

Comment: your cordinate in array pathCoordinatesArray .. Right ?

Comment: the coordinates in that array  are each with distance 1000 or greater then . finally i have to store in that array the coordinates each with 1000 or greater then between pointA and pointB

Comment: @jogendra: Dude pleas help me i have been trying it from many days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your loop code like this

```
for (int i=0 ; i<path.count; i++) {

    if (pathCoordinatesArray.count == 0) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D temp2d = [path coordinateAtIndex:i];
        CLLocation *tempLoc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:temp2d.latitude longitude:temp2d.longitude];

        [pathCoordinatesArray addObject:tempLoc];
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationCoordinate = [path coordinateAtIndex:i];
    CLLocation *destinationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:destinationCoordinate.latitude longitude:destinationCoordinate.longitude];

    [self checkDistanceForSource:[pathCoordinatesArray lastObject] andDestination:destinationLocation];
    }
}
```